# Pandas dataframe, Filter and recursive search

Tags: pandas, recursion

I want to filter a pandas dataframe and add some data in a recursive way.

The dataframe shows a hierachie in 'Level'. Level 1 is the parent level and 2 to n are children of level 1.

[image: dataframe]

What I am trying to do is to filter all rows with an 'E' or 'V' in [Status].

```
data = {
    "Level": [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4],
    "Status": ["-", "-", "E", "-", "-", "V", "-", "-", "-"],
    "Item": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8", "Item 9"]
}

# Load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a new DataFrame by filtering rows with Status "E" or "V"
filtered_df = df.loc[df['Status'].isin(['E', 'V'])].copy()
```

Then I want to add the parent levels of each child so that only row 0, 2, 3, 4, 5 are displayed.

[image: filtered dataframe]

Could anyone help me out?

Best regards,
Maik

Comment: Please add expected output

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you don't need recursion, you can simply iterate in reverse order, keeping track of the last levels that matched your condition:

```
def filter_indices(df):
    last_level = set()
    keep = set()
    for i, l, s in zip(df.index[::-1],
                       df.loc[::-1, 'Level'],
                       df.loc[::-1, 'Status'].isin(['V', 'E'])):
        if s:
            keep.add(i)
            last_level.add(l)
        if l+1 in last_level:
            keep.add(i)
            last_level.add(l)
            last_level.remove(l+1)
    return list(keep)

out = df.loc[filter_indices(df)]
```

*NB. this assumes unique indices, if not first `reset_index`.*

Output:

```
   Level Status    Item
0      1      -  Item 1
2      2      E  Item 3
3      2      -  Item 4
4      3      E  Item 5
5      2      V  Item 6
```

##### variant to also get the matching children:

```
def filter_indices(df):
    last_level = {}
    keep = set()
    children = {}
    for i, l, s in zip(df.index[::-1],
                       df.loc[::-1, 'Level'],
                       df.loc[::-1, 'Status'].isin(['V', 'E'])):
        if s:
            keep.add(i)
            last_level[l] = i
        if l+1 in last_level:
            children[i] = last_level[l+1]
            keep.add(i)
            last_level[l] = i
            del last_level[l+1]
    return list(keep), children

idx, children = filter_indices(df)

out = df.loc[idx].assign(child_idx=children)
```

Output:

```
   Level Status    Item  child_idx
0      1      -  Item 1        2.0
2      2      E  Item 3        NaN
3      2      -  Item 4        4.0
4      3      E  Item 5        NaN
5      2      V  Item 6        NaN
```